# ld: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 when defining a global var in a header

Tags: c++, macos, duplicates, x86-64, symbols

How to solve this problem?

Just getting following errors:

g++ output:

```
duplicate symbol _game in:
    /var/folders/w6/yqp0s0t92hl5g842hg8tztfr0000gn/T/main-62666f.o
    /var/folders/w6/yqp0s0t92hl5g842hg8tztfr0000gn/T/Game-a5a31d.o
duplicate symbol _game in:
    /var/folders/w6/yqp0s0t92hl5g842hg8tztfr0000gn/T/main-62666f.o
    /var/folders/w6/yqp0s0t92hl5g842hg8tztfr0000gn/T/Write-83f8ee.o
```

It seems like the problem is not in the header files.

EDIT: Header files look like this:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "Color.h"
#include "Tile.h"

class Game
{
  public:

    Game();
    ~Game();
    Color getActivePlayer();
    void setStarttile(Tile Firststarttile);
    Color togglePlayer();
    void setRunning(bool run);
    char newActiveplayer;
    void run();
    void runsecondmethod();

  private:
    Game(const Game &);
    Color Activeplayer;
    Tile *Starttile;
    bool Running;
}game;

#endif
```

Comment: Are you including `.cpp` files in other files? Do your `.h` have header guards? We can't know just by those errors alone.

Comment: No we are not including any .cpp files.

Comment: Do you *define* a function in a header file, instead of only declaring it?

Comment: No we just declare them. They are defined in the .cpp files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have instantiated a `Game` instance in your header file "Game.h", and since this is being included in multiple files you end up with multiple instances of `game` at link time. Change:

```
class Game
{
  public:

  ...

}game;
```

to:

```
class Game
{
  public:

  ...

};

extern Game game;
```

and then add:

```
Game game;
```

in **one** of your .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

In your header file (the one included from Write.cpp and GameBoard.cpp), you're likely to have an instantiation instead of a declaration.

Common cases/pitfalls :

- missing `extern` before global variables
- having function implementation (i.e. having `void foo(Bar& b) {}` instead of `void foo(Bar& b);`

Without more details, hard to help...

Look for where `addnewtile` function is defined for example...

*EDIT*

With more details

```
class Game
{
   (zip)
}game;
```

This is declaring the class Game and creating a game object each time you include the header file.

Use

```
class Game
{
   (zip)
};
```

In the header file and `Game game;` in the cpp

Or use a singleton pattern / static instance.

Comment: addnewtile is a class not a function

Comment: we don't use global variables and no function implementation in header files